# What does the tee l2r or r2l argument mean?

Tags: linux, bash, tee, socat

I saw a socat example [here](https://gist.github.com/mario21ic/c09f0a648130ad6a91abdde41cb011c8#file-socat_examples-L43), where they use

```
tee l2r | socat - "TCP:remote:5555"  | tee r2l
```

what does the `l2r` or `r2l` mean?

Comment: `l` and `r` may mean `local` and `remote` and not `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-option arguments passed to `tee` are just the paths of the files it tees its output to.

So that means that what is read from stdin is teed both to a pipe to `socat` (to be sent over the TCP socket) and a file called `l2r` in the current working directory and `socat`'s output (what is received from the TCP socket) is teed both to stdout and a file called `r2l` in the current working directory.

The exact name of those files has no significance to `tee`.

Comment: Ohh, I missed the files, because I didn't see them on my system. But I just looked at the wrong directory. Maybe I should take a break :)